# how to install Cassandra and how to set Cassandra username and password & its proper connector for netbeans

Tags: netbeans, cassandra, connection, connector

I am Net beans user and I am forbidden to use any other database except Cassandra so I install it simply from an open source. But it did not ask me for any username or password while installing Cassandra(So I do not its username and password) but Net beans always ask password and username to connect it to any data base(Like Cassandra & Oracle). & I do not know the Username & password for Cassandra...  can you help me how to find Username and password for Cassandra And Net beans connector to Cassandra if any. Or steps for how to connect Net beans & Cassandra.

Comment: The NBCassandra plugin asks "Authentication required?", just choose No...

Answer (score 2):

By default, Cassandra defaults to no authentication and no authorization.

In your Cassandra installation, open `cassandra.yaml` in  `conf` folder and set:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
```

Restart your Cassandra server. ( `nodetool stopdaemon` can be used to stop)

After that you should be able to login with: Username: `cassandra` and Password: `cassandra`

More information about creating users can be found here:
[How do you create the first user in Cassandra DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213786/how-do-you-create-the-first-user-in-cassandra-db)

Coming to using Cassandra in Netbeans, you can use this plugin, you need to install it manually.

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/59444

Comment: I have same situation. I tried to change the value of "authenticator" and "authorizer" from AllowAllAuthenticator and AllowAllAuthorizer in PasswordAuthenticator respectively CassandraAuthorizer but after restart, the Cassandra CQL Shell does not remain opened. Am I doing something wrong?