# Authentication via username and password in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In order to create a DBLink from Oracle to Cassandra, I am trying to have a connection in Cassandra via username and password.
By default, the installation of Cassandra does not ask for username.
Searching here, I found a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645539/how-to-install-cassandra-and-how-to-set-cassandra-username-and-password-its-pr) where it is described the steps for that.
unfortunately, when I modify the `authenticator` and `authorizer` parameters, the Cassandra CQL Shell opens and immediately closes.

Cassandra Installer version: datastax-ddc-64bit-3.9.0.msi

OS:                          Windows 7

Can someone tell me how to solve this, please?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Solve CQL Shell error edit cqlshrc file.

Default location in windows is `C:\Users\USER\.cassandra` where USER is windows username.

In cqlshrc file edit following:

```
[authentication]
;; If Cassandra has auth enabled, fill out these options
username = cassandra
password = cassandra
```

Note cassandra is default username & password which is also a superuser.

Comment: It is working but what about if I want to connect with other user? Should I connect to Cassandra with default login credentials and create the new user from there?

Comment: create a new role in cassandra and use that user.. Other option is to run cqlsh from command line.... `<CASSANDRA_INSTALL_DIR>\bin\cqlsh -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>`