# Can username and password be passed in connection url for cassandra

Tags: cassandra, database-connection, cdata

I want to ask if we can pass username and password in database connection url
Example:

```
jdbc:cassandra:keyspace=keyspace1;host=host;port=port;user=user;password=password;
```

I'm using cdata drivers for apache cassandra.
And if yes, how can i create a user with password whom I'll via the connection url?
And no, the documentation on datastax is not helping me out.

Comment: How to create the first user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213786/how-do-you-create-the-first-user-in-cassandra-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. Set the *AuthScheme* Connection property to 'Basic' and set the *User* and *Password* connection properties, in addition to the other necessary properties:

```
jdbc:cassandra:AuthSchem=BASIC;User=<username>;Password=<password>;...
```

@Aaron offers the solution for creating the first user: [How do you create the first user in Cassandra DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213786/how-do-you-create-the-first-user-in-cassandra-db)

From the [online CData JDBC Driver for Cassandra help](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/RCC/jdbc/pg_connectionj.htm):

> The driver supports Basic authentication with login credentials and
>   the additional authentication features of DataStax Enterprise (DSE)
>   Cassandra. The following sections detail connection properties your
>   authentication method may require.
>
> You need to set *AuthScheme* to the value corresponding to the
>   authenticator configured for your system. You specify the
>   authenticator in the authenticator property in the cassandra.yaml
>   file. This file is typically found in `/etc/dse/cassandra`. or through
>   the DSE Unified Authenticator on DSE Cassandra.
>
> **Basic Authentication**
>
> Basic authentication is supported through Cassandra's built-in default
>   PasswordAuthenticator.
>
> - Set the AuthScheme property to 'BASIC' and set the *User* and *Password*    properties.
> - In the cassandra.yaml file, set the authenticator    property to 'PasswordAuthenticator'.
>
> **Kerberos Authentication**
>
> Kerberos authentication is supported through DataStax Enterprise
>   Unified Authentication.
>
> - Set the *AuthScheme* property to 'KERBEROS' and set the *User* and *Password* properties.
> - Set the KerberosKDC, KerberosRealm, and KerberosSPN properties.
> - In the cassandra.yaml file, set the authenticator property to "com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator".
> - Modify the authentication_options section in the dse.yaml file, specifying the default_schema and other_schemas properties as
>     'kerberos'.
> - Modify the kerberos_options section in the dse.yaml file, specifying the keytab, service_principle, http_principle and qop
>     properties
>
> **LDAP Authentication**
>
> LDAP authentication is supported through DataStax Enterprise Unified
>   Authentication.
>
> - Set the *AuthScheme* property to 'LDAP' and set the User and Password properties.
> - In the cassandra.yaml file, set the authenticator property to "com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.auth.DseAuthenticator".
> - Modify the authentication_options section in the dse.yaml file, specifying the default_schema and other_schemas properties as 'ldap'.
> - Modify the ldap_options section in the dse.yaml file, specifying the server_host, server_port, search_dn, search_password,
>     user_search_base, and user_search_filter properties
>
> **Using PKI**
>
> You can specify a client certificate to authenticate the driver with
>   *SSLClientCert*, *SSLClientCertType*, *SSLClientCertSubject*, and *SSLClientCertPassword*.